# Apache Netbeans changing default delimiter

Tags: netbeans, localization, delimiter

Despite having changed the pcs regional delimiter to a "." Netbeans 12 is still using a ",". I have tried adding the following to the netbeans.conf file but it has no effect:

-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US

How do you force netbeans to use a particular local via the conf file?

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the delimiter on win 10 but not the entire format for the pc. By changing the whole format to English UK, Netbeans honours the change.